# flattest fetching an array now showing react native

Tags: api, async-await, react-native-ios, fetch-api, react-native-flatlist

I am not getting any items from my api array and is it not populating into my flattest. I am wanting to to create a leaderboard pulling in the user name & points from my api which is an array.

down below is what I have for for my project, I did take the api out. I have no clue whats going on here.

I am using async/await fetch method .

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],}
}

async getLeaderBoard() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('api_here', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer + token'

            },
        });
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
        throw error;
    };
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.getLeaderBoard()
}

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log(item.title);
    this._carousel.triggerRenderingHack();
    return (
        <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 200, borderRadius: 12, marginTop: 10 }} source={{ uri: item }} />
    );
}

render() {
    return (<View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height, alignItems: 'center' }}>


        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>LEADER BOARD</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.getLeaderBoard}
            keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Text>
                {`${item.name} ${item.points}`}
            </Text>
            }>
        </FlatList>
    </View>)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not storing the data anywhere. Your method `getLeaderBoard` isn't a part of the state, you misunderstood it. You should do as below:

Your method `getLeaderBoard`:

```
async getLeaderBoard() {
   try {
       let response = await fetch('api_here', {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: {
               Accept: 'application/json',
               Authorization: 'Bearer + token'

           },
       });
       let responseJson = await response.json();
       this.setState({data : responseJson}) // Store the API response on the state
   } catch (error) {
       console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
       throw error;
   };
}
```

Your render method:

```
render() {
   return (<View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height, alignItems: 'center' }}>


       <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
           <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>LEADER BOARD</Text>
       </View>
       <FlatList
           data={this.state.data}  // The data is passed to the list
           keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
           renderItem={({ item }) =>
           <Text>
               {`${item.name} ${item.points}`}
           </Text>
           }>
       </FlatList>
   </View>)
}
```

I recommend you to read the [State and Lifecycle docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: thanks for saving me the headache, I thought I was calling on the wrong thing. thanks for pointing that out and the doc is really helpful!

Comment: @ShawnNguyen, you're welcome! The docs is always handy, hope it helps you!